# Topological space represented as a topos?

Tags: general-topology, topos-theory

Wikipedia states that Toposes "are in a sense a generalization of point-set topology".

This suggests to me that any topological space can be represented as a topos. Is this true? How do we do this?

Comment: The category of sheaves over a topological space is a topos.

Comment: Not just sheaves, but pre-sheaves too.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, so we cannot actually represent a topological space as a topos? e.g. where the points in the topological space are objects, and the topology is somehow represented in the morphisms?

Comment: Only sober topological spaces can be so represented IIRC. I'm no expert though.

Comment: maybe look at [this](http://www.ams.org/notices/200409/what-is-illusie.pdf) ?

Comment: It is a failed attempt to define topology with category theory that has been patched by considering only sober (I kid you not) topologies.  Soberity is of no topological interest.  Soberity is needed for category theory (also called abstract nonsense) to be able to haphazzardly define topology.  Whereupon, lo and behold, comes forth pointless topology which, as far as topology is concerned, is pointless.

Comment: The above comment is not quite a fair account of the situation. There are many classes of space, including all Hausdorff spaces, that are sober, so we get to pass between a space and its category of sheaves for many useful spaces. And even when a space is not sober, its category of sheaves is usually far from uninteresting. I also recommend reading Johnstone's *The Point of Pointless Topology* for a reasonably readable account of what the field is about from one of its major contributors.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine , Is it correct to say that the use of toposes for topology is always within the context of pointless topology, or is there also a topos approach to point-set topology?

Comment: Almost entirely within the setting of point-set toplogy; it's just that sheaves on a topological space are really sheaves on the partial order of open sets, so when asking how well the sheaves describe the space, we are forced to consider the relationship between spaces and said lattices of open sets. And this leads us to use some of the tools of pointless topology. But sheaves generally are an entirely mainstream tool in algebraic geometry.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine, ok that clarifies. And are sheaves ever studied without the use of category theory? (in principle they can be defined without reference to categories I assume).

Comment: It can be, and I've seen some older papers present it as its own thing. But in modern writings it's more common to just talk about them as functors.